# Copying records from one table and to another based on the value of a yes/no field

Tags: forms, ms-access, if-statement, macros

I'm beginner in MS Access and I have managed to make my own database for customers who sign up for soccer academy. Now what I want to learn is how to make a macro to do the following action:

"If a Yes/No field in Table1 is equal to 'Yes' then copy the record from Table1 and paste it to Table2"

I signed up a lot of new players because I gave them 1st day free and not all of them continue after that. What I want from this system is if that new player pays, I want him in a separate table to further calculate financial stuff.

I have made a form to sign up players and two tables, one for newly registered and one for those who continue with us and paid.

Answer (score 0):

What you're going to want to do is create an Append query.  You can do this by following these steps:

1. Click on Create, then Query Design from the ribbon on top
2. Select Table1 from the Show Table popup, and click "Add"
3. Click "Close" from the Show Table popup
4. Highlight all your fields, then click-n-drag them into the grid at the bottom
5. In your Yes/No field, set the Criteria to Yes
6. Click "Design" from the ribbon on top and choose Append
7. Set the Append To Table Name to be Table2
8. Save the query

Then, just set up a macro to run the query you've just created.

Without specific information, that's the best I can do.  But it's definitely the easiest way to go.  You can write VBA to do it, but that requires a bit more knowledge